# Finding value of $\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{(1-x^n)}{(1-x)}$ without using L'Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, definite-integrals

How do I find the value of $$\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{(1-x^n)}{(1-x)}$$

I know it could be done through L'Hospital, but I am struggling to find another solution.

Comment: The top factors.

Comment: Or, if you like, this is a derivative in secret.

Comment: try substituting x=1+h as h approches to 0 and use binomial theorem

Comment: Use $1-x^n=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{n-1})$. And this is a very common factorization, you should remember it.

Comment: You did not say that $n$ is a positive integer?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2229949/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2999527/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1789815/42969

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify the expression by writting $(1 - x^n)$ as $(1 - x) f(x)$,
where $f(x)$is equal to $(1 + x + x^2 + ... +x^{n - 1})$. Now you get:

$$ \lim_{x \to 1} {1-x^n \over 1-x} = \lim_{x \to 1} {(1-x)(1 + x + x^2 + ... +x^{n - 1}) \over 1-x} \tag 1$$

$$ \lim_{x \to 1} {1-x^n \over 1-x} = \lim_{x \to 1} ({1 + x + x^2 + ... +x^{n - 1}})=n \tag 2$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} & =\lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^n-1^n}{x-1} \\
& =\left.\frac{d}{d x}\left(x^n\right)\right|_{x=1} \quad  \textrm{ (By the definition of derivative )} \\
& =\left.n x^{n-1}\right|_{x=1} \\
& =n
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Substitution**
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} = & \lim _{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-(1-y)^n}{y}, \text { where } y-1-x \\
= & \lim _{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{1- \displaystyle  \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right)(-y)^k}{y} \\
= & \lim _{y \rightarrow 0}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right)(-1)^{k+1} y^{k-1}\right) \\
= & \left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
1
\end{array}\right)(-1)^2 \\
= & n
\end{aligned}
$$